# DHTML Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, dhtml

I need to generate Dhtml menus. but i want to use a tool.
does anyone know what FREE tool should I use?
I used CoffeeCup Dhtml menu builder but i does not compatible with IE.

Comment: There's lots of Google matches for `DHTML menus`. Pick the one you like. I don't use them, so I can't advise. I prefer jQuery nowadays for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/